# Flask-SQLAlchemy how to have one class that can be used in multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I change which table to insert class instances into? With PostgreSQL syntax I can specify which table I want by saying `INSERT INTO departures...` however with SQLAlchemy, the table is tied to the class so I can't change the table throughout the app.

I've looked into this quite a bit and below if the best solution I could find:

```
def create_model(table_type):
    class Flight(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = table_type
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        username = db.Column(db.String, nullable = False)
        ...
    globals().update(locals())
```

The way I use the above model is by choosing the table_type before I perform any action with the db like this:

```
create_model("departures")
db.session.add(flight1)
db.session.commit()
```

Is there a better way to do this? It seems pretty inefficient and causes trouble when importing the class into different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database model is a representation of a table and its data. I don't see a reason to have 2 tables with the same data and column definitions in it and afaik, you can't.

Looking at your model and example, I'd suggest you add a `type` column that contains either `departures` or `arrivals`. This way you can keep the data clean and still be able to query on what you want.